# Why is Xamarin DatePicker Binding causing a navigation failure?

Tags: xamarin, binding, datepicker, navigation, prism

I am using Prism and Autofac with Xamarin.Forms 4.0 with an MVVM architecture. Using the Navigation.NavigateAsync("MyPage") works unless I have a binding to the Date object with my ViewModel.

The page renders properly and I am navigated to it if my DatePicker has no binding.

```
<DatePicker x:Name="ProcessStartDate" Format="D" MinimumDate="01/01/2000"  />
```

However the following will cause me to never navigate to the page.

```
<DatePicker x:Name="ProcessStartDate" Format="D" MinimumDate="01/01/2000" Date="{Binding SelectedStartDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

The property in the View Model, MyVM, looks like this.

```
private DateTime selectedStartDate;
public DateTime SelectedStartDate
{
    get
    {
        return selectedStartDate;
    }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref selectedStartDate, value);
        sample.ProcessStartDate = value;
    }
}
```

Navigation with the following code fails with the Binding in XAML above:

```
INavigationResult status;
try
{
    var parameters = new NavigationParameters();
    parameters.Add("CurrentSample", SelectedSample);

    status = await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MyPage", parameters); //MyPage is registered with MyVM

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string mess = ex.Message;
}
```

My work-around is to add an event handler to the code-behind.

```
<DatePicker x:Name="ProcessStartDate" Format="D" MinimumDate="01/01/2000" DateSelected="OnStartDateSelected"
```

So now my code-behind has a handler:

```
void OnStartDateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs args)
{
    SampleDetailsViewModel vm = BindingContext as SampleDetailsViewModel;
    vm.SelectedStartDate = args.NewDate;
}
```

I have a work-around for this page, But I don't want put code in the code-behind. This breaks the MVVM standard that I've managed to maintain on the other seven pages of the app. Am I Binding improperly with the DatePicker?

Comment: Whats the message in the exception?

Comment: No exception was caught. I have an async call inside a try ... catch, but the debugger simply leaves the calling method. The constructors of the VM and Page are called, but the page is not rendered.

Comment: Prism by defailt doesnt throw exception on navigation fail, check the exception inside `INavigationResult status`

Comment: No value is returned to status. It's as if the instruction pointer is somewhere I can't see it. Perhaps the exception is in another thread. I'll have to create a global exception handler to find it probably.

Comment: Just guessing here, it usually happens when app runs to an infinite loop... what does this do `sample.ProcessStartDate = value;`? does it cyclically update `SelectedStartDate` again?

Comment: I should have taken that out for clarity. It's another object that ultimately gets sent back to the API. I verified that SelectedStartDate is not in a loop with a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Binding `SelectedStartDate`, you are not initializing it, making it binding to a **null**, because you have set the Binding Mode to **`"TwoWay"`**.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingmode?view=netframework-4.8) you can find the various types of binding modes, quoting:

> Causes changes to either the source property or the target property to
>   automatically update the other. This type of binding is appropriate
>   for editable forms or other fully-interactive UI scenarios.

a solution would be something like this (if you wanna keep the TwoWay mode, and dont mind starting with an default selected):

```
private DateTime selectedStartDate = DateTime.Now;
```

**Or**

Making the binding mode to **`"OneWayToSource"`**, this makes updates to the binding source without, and not the target (remember that this way you can't change the selected date from the binding, only the datepicker can).

> Updates the source property when the target property changes.

**Or**

If you wanna keep the TwoWay Mode and not having a default date selected, the way you did with code behind is a nice workaround.

Comment: I initialized to DateTime.Now in my DateTime properties and now it renders!